# every page of pdf border bottom needed for last tr using nreco.pdf library

Tags: c#, .net, nreco

[image]

```js
function subst() {
    var vars = {};

   var x = document.location.search.substring(1).split('&');
    for (var i in x) { var z = x[i].split('=', 2); vars[z[0]] = unescape(z[1]); }
```

```cs
    // Get the total number of pages
    var totalPages = parseInt(vars['topage']);

    // Iterate through each page
    for (var currentPage = 1; currentPage <= totalPages; currentPage++) {
        // Select the last <tr> on the current page
        var lastTr = document.querySelector('.page' + currentPage + ' tr:last-child');

        // Apply bottom border to the last <tr> on the current page
        if (lastTr) {
            lastTr.style.borderBottom = '1px solid black';
        }
    }

    // Hide the element with id "lastpage" if there's more than one page
    if (totalPages > 1) {
        document.getElementById("lastpage").style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: please help me i am hanging on this issue